# Propagate exception to next catch

Tags: php, exception

i have this code:

```
<?php
[...]

// Authentication error
catch(AuthException $e)
{
    // TODO: Save fault to auth into DB

    // Propagate exception
    throw $e;
}

// Common exception
catch(Exception $e)
{
    // TODO: Log error here

    $response = JsonResponse(array("error" => $e->getMessage()));
    $response->send();
}
```

I want to able to throw AuthException and Exception, and want to be sure that AuthException's catch will store error into db, and as common Exception will be returned as error.
But now I have error, that I have uncaugth exception. 
Or maybe I need to log error in the AuthException's constructor?

Comment: you are throwing the exception after being caught, so if you don't have another layer of code that would catch it and do smth with it, you will have an `Uncaught exception` error

Comment: Why don't you simply add a column in `$response` in your `catch(AuthException $e)` bloc ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to catch each exception, I guess you wanna do something like this ?

```
try {
      //...
} catch(Exception $e){

  if($e instanceof AuthException ) {
    // Log error here
  }

    $response = JsonResponse(array("error" => $e->getMessage()));
    $response->send();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is. But this way doesn't feel natural. Because I can avoid AuthException, and simply switch/case or smth similar to resolve type of the error in one catch block